# Android date format with Month

Tags: java, android, date-formatting, date-parsing

How to get the Android date format "7/25/2021" to July/25/2021

Here is the portion of the code

mDisplayDate is the Textview

`mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(view -> { Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`

```
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

`String dateLong = month + "/" + day+ "/" + year;`

`mDisplayDate.setText(dateLong);`

Comment: I hope this documentation page may help: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @AdarshAnurag Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android.

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("7/25/2021", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM/d/u", Locale.ENGLISH))` yields `July/25/2021`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a **switch case**

```
String monthStr = "";

switch(month) {
    case 1:
        monthStr = "January";
        break;
    case 2:
        monthStr = "February";
        break;
   // and else
}

String dateLong = monthStr + "/" + day+ "/" + year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the android documentation link, that I shared in the comments to learn about SimpleDateFormat.

The Pattern to be used should be ***MMMM/dd/yyyy***

- MMMM - gives month name
- dd - gives the days of the month
- yyyy - gives the year

  ```
   Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM/dd/yyyy");
   String today = formatter.format(date);
   mDisplayDate.setText(today);
  ```

Note: You may use MMM for month names in 3 letters only.

Read more about [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) here.